# Why shuffle doesn't work after I added new functionality of changing a gameboard size in a slider-puzzle game?

Tags: javascript, debugging, game-development, shuffle

I created a slider-puzzle game and recently decided to reafctor the code using OOP. Besides I added a new functionality, so a player can change the size of the game board (3X3, 4X4, 5X5 etc.) by pressing a sertain button. But somehow a shuffle function stopped working. If you have any ideas of what I might do wrong, I will be very grateful if you let me know.

```
"use strict";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Elements
const body = document.body;
const root = document.querySelector(".root");
const buttons = document.createElement("div");
const table = document.querySelector(".table");
const timeAndMoves = document.createElement("div");
const cubeSize = 125;
let cubes = [];
let gameRoundResults = {round: [], moves: [], time: []};

let countMoves = 0;
let gameRound = 0;
let cube, timer, left, top, tr, td;
let rowColumnLength = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; // the default size of the game board - 4 columns and 4 rows
let boardSize = [9, 16, 15, 36, 49, 64];

let cubesArray = [];

let blankSpace = document.querySelector(".blank_space");
blankSpace = {
  // blank space coords
};

// calculating coordinates of each cube and setting style
function getCoords(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}

function setElementStyle(a, b) {
  return `${a * b}px`;
}

// changing position of cubes
function changePosition(i) {
  let cube = cubes[i];
  const blankSpaceLeft = blankSpace.left;
  const blankSpaceTop = blankSpace.top;

  let coordsLeft = getCoords(blankSpace.left, cube.left);
  let coordsTop = getCoords(blankSpace.top, cube.top);

  if (
    (blankSpaceLeft === cube.left && blankSpaceTop === cube.top) ||
    coordsLeft + coordsTop > 1
  ) {
    return;
  } else {
    countMoves++;
    calcMoves.textContent = `Moves: ${countMoves}`;
  }

  cube.element.style.left = setElementStyle(blankSpace.left, cubeSize);
  cube.element.style.top = setElementStyle(blankSpace.top, cubeSize);

  blankSpace.top = cube.top;
  blankSpace.left = cube.left;
  cube.top = blankSpaceTop;
  cube.left = blankSpaceLeft;

  const winCondition = cubes.every(
    (cube) => cube.value - 1 === cube.top * rowColumnLength + cube.left
  );

  if (winCondition) {
    winAnnouncement();
    clearInterval(timer);
    gameRound++;
    gameRoundResults.round.push(gameRound);
    gameRoundResults.moves.push(countMoves);
    gameRoundResults.time.push(setTimer.textContent);
  }
}

// resetting the game, so after clicking on a shuffle button the original game board won't overlay newly shuffled cubes
const resetGame = () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  setTimer.textContent = `Time: 00:00`;
  countMoves = 0;
  calcMoves.textContent = `Moves: ${countMoves}`;
  [...root.children].forEach((el) => {
    root.removeChild(el); //removing elements from the board
  });
  [...table.children].forEach((el) => {
    table.removeChild(el); //removing elements from the board
  });
  cubes.splice(0); // deleting all elements starting from index 0
  blankSpace.top = 0; // resetting coordinates
  blankSpace.left = 0;
};

// creating a timer
const setTimer = document.createElement("div");
setTimer.classList.add("timer");
setTimer.textContent = `Time: 00:00`;
body.append(setTimer);

function startTimer() {
  let sec = 0;
  let min = 0;

  timer = setInterval(() => {
    setTimer.textContent =
      "Time: " + `${min}`.padStart(2, 0) + ":" + `${sec}`.padStart(2, 0);
    sec++;

    if (sec >= 60) {
      sec = 0;
      min++;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// creating moves counter
const calcMoves = document.createElement("div");
calcMoves.classList.add("count_moves");
calcMoves.textContent = `Moves: ${countMoves}`;
body.append(calcMoves);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Creating buttons using OOP and adding event listeners to each of them

class Button {
  constructor(name, attribute, classList, textContent, value) {
    this.name = document.createElement("button");
    this.name.setAttribute("id", attribute);
    this.name.classList.add(classList);
    this.textContent = this.name.textContent = textContent;
    buttons.append(this.name);
  }

  //Methods that will be added to .prototype property
  addEventShuffle() {
    this.name.addEventListener("click", function () {
      shuffle(cubesArray);
    });
  }

  addEventStop() {
    this.name.addEventListener("click", function () {
      clearInterval(timer);
    });
  }

  addEventResult() {
    this.name.addEventListener("click", function () {
      clearInterval(timer);
      tableCreate();
      showResults();
    });
  }

  clickOnlyOnce() {
    this.name.addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.disabled = "disabled";
    });
  }

  clickOnlyOnceDisabled() {
    this.name.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }

  renderCubesNumber(number){
    this.name.addEventListener("click", function () {
      cubesArray.push(...Array(boardSize[number]).keys());
      setPosition(boardSize = boardSize[number], rowColumnLength = rowColumnLength[number]);
      console.log(cubesArray);
    });
  }
}

const shuffleButton = new Button(
  "shuffleButton",
  "button",
  "shuffleButton",
  "SHUFFLE"
);
const stopButton = new Button("stopButton", "button", "stopButton", "STOP");
const saveButton = new Button("saveButton", "button", "saveButton", "SAVE");
const resultsButton = new Button( "resultsButton", "button", "resultsButton", "RESULT");


shuffleButton.addEventShuffle();
stopButton.addEventStop();
resultsButton.addEventResult();
resultsButton.clickOnlyOnce();

// Creating size buttons
for(let i = 3; i <= 8; i++){
new Button("rowsCols", "button", "row_col_length", `${i}X${i}`).renderCubesNumber(i - 3);
}

// implementing shuffle functionality

function shuffle(cubesArray) {
  for (let i = cubesArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    resetGame(); // deleting original game board
    setPosition(cubesArray); // creating a new shuffled game board
    startTimer();
    
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));

    [cubesArray[i], cubesArray[j]] = [cubesArray[j], cubesArray[i]];

    // [cubesArray[i], cubesArray[newPos]] = [cubesArray[newPos], cubesArray[i]]; //swapping original and randomized coordinates
    console.log(
      ([cubesArray[i], cubesArray[j]] = [cubesArray[j], cubesArray[i]])
    );
  }
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Creating banners using OOP
class Banner {
  constructor(name, classList, textContent, bannerMessage, bannerMessageClass) {
    this.name = document.createElement("div");
    this.name.classList.add(classList);
    this.bannerMessage = document.createElement("h2");
    this.bannerMessage.classList.add(bannerMessageClass);
    this.bannerMessage.textContent = textContent;
    root.append(this.bannerMessage);
    root.append(this.name);
  }

  removeBanner() {
    this.name.addEventListener("click", () => {
      resultBanner.classList.remove("result_banner");
      resultsButton.clickOnlyOnceDisabled();
    });
  }
}

// const startBanner = new Banner("startBanner","start_banner", `Slider puzzle challenge Click on 'Shuffle' to start the game!`, "bannerMessage","banner_message"
// );

// create pop-up if the user wins
function winAnnouncement() {
  const winMessage = new Banner(
    "winAnnounce",
    "win_announce",
    `Congrats! You solved the puzzle! Moves: ${countMoves} | ${setTimer.textContent}`,
    "winMessage",
    "win_message"
  );
}

// Creating a result banner
function showResults() {
  const resultBanner = document.createElement("div");
  resultBanner.classList.add("result_banner");
  const closeBanner = document.createElement("div");
  closeBanner.classList.add("close_banner");
  root.append(resultBanner);
  table.append(closeBanner);
  tableCreate();

  const resultMessage = document.createElement("h2");
  resultMessage.classList.add("banner_message");
  resultBanner.append(resultMessage);

  closeBanner.addEventListener("click", () => {
    resultBanner.classList.remove("result_banner");
    resultsButton.clickOnlyOnceDisabled();
    [...table.children].forEach((el) => {
      table.removeChild(el); //removing elements from the board
    });
  });
}

function tableCreate() {
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  tbl.classList.add("score_table");

  for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    tr = tbl.insertRow();
    td = tr.insertCell();

    if (gameRound === i + 1) {
      td.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
          `Round: ${i + 1} | Moves: ${gameRoundResults.moves[i]} | ${gameRoundResults.time[i]}`
        )
      );
    } else {
      td.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(`Round: ${i + 1} | Moves: 0 | Time: 00:00`)
      );
    }

    td.style.border = "1px solid black";
  }
  table.appendChild(tbl);
}

buttons.classList.add("button");
body.append(buttons);



// creating cubes
function setPosition() {
  for (let i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    cube = document.createElement("div");
    cube.classList.add("cube");
    const value = i + 1; // adding +1 to the cubes' values to start the order from 1 (123...) instead of 0 (0123...)
    cube.textContent = value;

    left = i % rowColumnLength; // setting horizontal position
    cube.style.left = setElementStyle(cubeSize, left);
    top = (i - left) / rowColumnLength; // setting vertical position
    cube.style.top = setElementStyle(cubeSize, top);

    root.append(cube);

    if (value === boardSize) {
      // separating basic cubes with a blank space which is going to be the 16th cube
      cube.classList.add("blank_space"); // adding a class to the last cube, so it'll be possible to hide it using css
      blankSpace.top = top;
      blankSpace.left = left;
      blankSpace.value = value;
      blankSpace.element = cube;
      cubes.push(blankSpace);
    } else {
      cubes.push({
        top: top,
        left: left,
        value: value,
        element: cube,
      });
    }

    cube.addEventListener("click", () => {
      changePosition(i);
    });
  }
}
setPosition();
```

[image]

To solve the problem I've tried to refactor the shuffle function, but nothing works. In the screenshot you can see the results of console.logs

Comment: I haven't looked through all your code, but one thing that I can see that you seem to be doing is creating [implicit global variables](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Things like  `setPosition(boardSize = boardSize[number], ...)` makes `boardSize` a global variable that's then shared across your script, and it might not be scopped how you think it is. Instead, pass these through as arguments for `setPosition()`. Other things like `cube`, `left` etc. should be declared with `const`/`let` (try and avoid `var` and that can be a bit unintuitive)

Comment: I suggest adding `"use strict";` at the very top of your code. Your code will crash at points that could lead to potentially buggy behavior (such as assigning to undeclared variables). You can go through the errors and fix each to ensure you're not accidentally creating global variables

Comment: @NickParsons thank you for your answer. I realised that some code snippets might be not enough informative, so I added all the code.

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your shuffle? I can see by your script shot that the first array is unshuffled, so it's ordered (which I guess is expected), and then it logs a bunch of arrays of length 2, with the elements in a random order (ie: shuffled?). But that's not what you're after?

Comment: Your console log on the last line of your shuffle of `[cubesArray[i], cubesArray[j]] = [cubesArray[j], cubesArray[i]]` will undo the swap that just occurred on the line above it. So your shuffle doesn't actually swap anything. Maybe that's causing you problems?

Comment: @NickParsons actually the first ordered array is fine, it's what I expected. Then I want to substitute the original array with a shuffled one. [cubesArray[i], cubesArray[j]] = [cubesArray[j], cubesArray[i]] does that. It worked before I added size buttons.

Comment: Did you try removing `console.log(([cubesArray[i], cubesArray[j]] = [cubesArray[j], cubesArray[i]]));` as suggested? This unswaps the swap that just occurred on the line above? Then logging `cubesArray`?

Comment: @NickParsons Oh, yes, I tried when you suggested that. The result is the same, unfortunately :( What's interesting I also tried to console.log the cubesArray after the shuffle, it really gets shuffled eventually. But still on the screen nothing happens.

Comment: @NickParsons thank you anyway for your time and efforts. I'll try to go back and check carefully every step to make sure what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a bit hard to debug without a runnable example. Usually we prefer if you create a [mre] which is a minified example of your issue so that it has as minimal code to reproduce your problem. Creating the example is also a way you can debug your issue (if you can’t reproduce it in your example code, then you know there’s some other code at play)